# D3 Appending Text to a SVG Rectangle

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm looking to append html onto a rectangle in D3 to give me a multiple line tooltip.  The bottom part is how I'm adding a rectangle which may be part of the problem.  The top is the code that should work in my world.

```
 newRect.().html(" <textArea font-family=Verdana font-size=20 fill=blue > Test " + "</br>" + "Test2 </textArea>");
```

Which does insert a text field into the SVG, it just doesn't display:
**HTML**:

```
<rect id="rectLabel" x="490" y="674" width="130" height="160" fill="red">
    <textarea fill="blue" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana"> Test </br>Test2 </textarea>
</rect>
```

I have a mouse over function which runs the following:

```
    newRect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", xCor)
    .attr("y", yCor)
    .attr("width", 130)
    .attr("height", 160)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("id", "rectLabel");
```

I think I should be doing this but it doesn't work.  It just removes the g.node that I'm trying to append to.

```
    newRect = $(this).enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", xCor)
    .attr("y", yCor)
    .attr("width", 130)
    .attr("height", 160)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("id", "rectLabel");
```

Question:
Why doesn't my text appear?  Ive tried .html, .textArea.  I want a multiple line label so I don't think .text will work correct?  Also, how should I be appending the rectangle?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

A `rect` can't contain a `text` element. Instead transform a `g` element with the location of text and rectangle, then append both the rectangle and the text to it:

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 3; })
    .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7341714

Multi-line labels are also a little tricky, you might want to check out this [wrap function](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321).

Comment: I wanted my text box to appear on mouse over so I was creating a function to do that.  But this ends up being a  g.node and won't let me append to it.  So should I be doing this when I create the data then just showing and hiding it or ?

Comment: The could work. Or attach the mouse listener to the g element, you'll be able to easily append from there.

Comment: Ahh, I'm guessing since I put my mouse listener on the node is why it is giving me g.node for my call to this?

Comment: g.node is what you want, append the text to that.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried the SVG [**text**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) element?

```
.append("text").text(function(d, i) { return d[whichevernode];})
```

[**rect**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect) element doesn't permit *text* element inside of it. It only allows descriptive elements (`<desc>, <metadata>, <title>`) and animation elements (`<animate>, <animatecolor>, <animatemotion>, <animatetransform>, <mpath>, <set>`)

Append the text element as a sibling and work on positioning.

**UPDATE**

Using *g* grouping, how about something like this? [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VmnEC/)

You can certainly move the logic to a CSS class you can append to, remove from the group (this.parentNode)

Comment: While this worked to append the element as a sibling (The sibling part was what I was doing wrong), there's got to be a more elegant solution thank hacking it onto the end?

Comment: After hours of tearing my hair out trying to map a touch event for a rect to specific text object (easy in v3, not so much in v4), your fiddle introduced me to `nextSibling`, which finally solved problem. Thank you!